# How to synchronize two of the jQuery Cycle 2?

Tags: jquery, synchronization, cycle

I am using Jquery Cycle 2 for the project of mine and it needs to deliver equal slides in both.
The method I use is:

```
$('.cycle-slideshow.big').on('cycle-after',function(e,opts) {
    $('.cycle-slideshow.small').cycle('goto',opts.nextSlide);
});
```

opts.nextSlide is only id of next slide in slider "small".

For some reason browsers shuffles pictures in the second slider so I can't use sequence number and that is the problem. How can sliders be synced?

Comment: I read it and it's no use that is why I need expert help

Comment: No, *we* need to see it. No one has any idea what `Jquery Cycle 2` is, and until we can get an idea it is impossible to help you.

Comment: OK, sorry, that is it: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.
Just replace Progressive Image Loading to simple and delete data-cycle-loader for IE.